# Saving oAuth user - Nuxt auth - github strategy

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I am trying to save the GitHub OAuth user logged to my user's database. I am using the Nuxt.js auth module for the functionality.

Auth setup in `Nuxt.config.js

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    local: {
      token: {
        property: 'data.token',
      },
      user: {
        property: 'data',
      },
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: 'login', method: 'post' },
        user: { url: 'byToken', method: 'get' },
        logout: { url: 'logout', method: 'get' },
      },
    },
    github: {
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
  },
},
```

Login.vue page

```html
<template>
   <button class="social-icons" @click="githubLogin()">
     Login with Github
   </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async githubLogin() {
      try {
        const response = await this.$authApi.loginWithGithub()
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Auth plugins file

```js
export default function (context, inject) {
  inject('authApi', {
    loginWithGithub,
  })
async function loginWithGithub() {
    try {
      await context.$auth.loginWith('github')
      // Get the required info from the user object set in vuex
      const user = context.$auth.user //This is undefined
      const userInfo = {
        oAuthId: user.id,
        username: user.login,
        name: user.name,
        bio: user.bio,
        email: user.email,
        profilePhoto: user.avatar_url,
        isOAuthUser: true,
      }
      // My api server to store the passed userinfo to db
      const response = await context.$axios.post('/socialRegister', userInfo)
      return response
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I click on the button to log in(Login.vue) using GitHub, the module successfully sets the access token received from GitHub to local storage and the user to state. But as you can see in the code(auth.js plugin file) after loginWith('github') `context.$auth.user` is undefined. Now my question is that how can i access the user info so that i can forward that info to my api server to store the user in DB.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error before.

Go tsconfig.json and change

```
{
"strict":false,
}
```

If it will not solve your problem, compare your tsconfig.json and [nuxt-auth original tsconfig.json](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/blob/dev/tsconfig.json)

Comment: Yo, thanks for looking into it. My project is a simple create-nuxt-app without typescript. So, I don't have a tsconfig.json in my project. I tried to implement 'strict: false' in my nuxt.config.js but no luck. Let me know if you have any other suggestions.✌